# WPF DataGrid: edit all cells, new row position, click once to edit

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I was wondering if anyone could point me into the right direction with DataGrids.

1. I'm trying to position the new row at the top of the grid
2. When the user clicks a cell all cells in the row move into an editable state.

Cheers

Comment: We decided to move away from the DataGrid by using a ListView (this allowed all rows to be in edit mode)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out for single click editing:
http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing

And this for New row formatting:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/11/05/wpf-datagrid-new-item-template-sample.aspx

I think positioning a new row on top might not be possible as the new item row is not part of the DataGrid's control template. Haven't given it a try though.